# Как передать js функцию на другую вкладку

Tags: javascript, node.js

хотел узнать как реализовать передачу js функции из консоли одной вкладки, в консоль другой вкладки, как-нибудь это реализуемо?
Решил сделать некий ресерч, перерыл интернет, результата 0. Создаю новую вкладку как window.open('http://ya.ru'), вот дальше возникает проблема с реализацией

Comment: Уж точно ничего нельзя при разных доменах. Вы просто не получите доступа к странице на ya.ru

Comment: если разные домены, то нельзя

Comment: домен один и тот же

Comment: Тогда в чём проблема? Что вы понимаете под «передать функцию»?

Comment: вот чтобы мне 100 раз открывая вкладку, каждый раз не вставлять один и тот же js код в консоль, хотел автоматизировать